# Is there a way to block inbound and outbound communication to mysql db in localhost for testing purposes?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Is there a way to block inbound and outbound traffic to mysql db in localhost for testing purposes?

Tried blocking ports using windows firewall features, but it did not help

Comment: Are you trying to test how your spring app will respond to an unavailable database connection?  Maybe just temporarily shutting down the database, or configuring your application to try connecting on the wrong port could give you the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your project to talk to the database by its local ip address instead of localhost or loopback. That will force it to cross your firewall since that request will go through your router unlike localhost. Go back to your firewall again and block traffic on mysql ports or by the service itself and now the traffic should be blocked in your app.